# Eloquent Get from Table A where it has one relation in B

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the records from Table A that has one and only one record in Table B, I'm not interested in records that have no records in B nor that have multiple records in B,
I tried using

```
TableA::whereHas('tableB')->get()
```

This didn't return A's where no records in B but I still don't need ones that have multiple in B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [has](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) so you can restrict query to fetch only those record which has one record in tableB model

```
TableA::has('tableB', '=', 1)->get()
```